# How can I install Geomesa on Google Cloud using BigTable

Tags: geomesa

How can I install Geomesa on Google Cloud using BigTable. I have data with lat , long and user identification. I need to create heat maps, path taken by most users, most frequented shops etc.I am looking for a solution on google cloud.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed answer. The best place to discuss GeoMesa installation issues is with the GeoMesa community on the https://locationtech.org/mailman/listinfo/geomesa-users mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with the [Quick Start tutorial](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-hbase.html) for HBase/Bigtable.

As you explore the other geomesa tutorials and documenation, you'll come across a heatmap [wps process](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-process/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/process/DensityProcess.scala) and [sld](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/9c3d38c54a149682a18493e84440a8d0435af8d8/docs/tutorials/_static/geomesa-examples-gdelt/heatmap.sld) for geoserver. The density wps is targeted for an accumulo data store, but should give you a starting point.